# how to pass data from UIWebview to user defaults or another view

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone

I have a embedded uiwebview in my app which will in turn call a webpage. This webpage contains some data which should be saved in the user defaults of the iphone. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It very much depends on what your page and data looks like... The basic approach is to use [`-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21) to retrieve content, e.g.:

```
NSString *script = @"document.getElementById('myTextInput').value";
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       result, @"MyTextInputValue",
                       // ... more?
                       nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"MyWebViewData"];
```

If the data is only used by scripts in the page, you could also simply use a script function that returns you one JSON string to store:

```
NSString *script = @"window.getJsonData()";
NSString *json   = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```